# Texture not properly applying, weight paint not subtracting

Tags: texturing, particles, weight-painting

I'm modeling a tree at the moment and I've followed everything the tutorial is saying, but the leaf texture on my leaves is still keeping the white edges. Along with that, I didn't use (or accidentally did) weight paint on the bottom of the twig, yet it is still putting leaves there. In some red spots, it's not really putting any leaves at all!

I've included the blender file as well as a picture.

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j55vJ7jik5sjs_yDUaNSeHcssM2y0bDc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j55vJ7jik5sjs_yDUaNSeHcssM2y0bDc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In order to help you I need to have all the texture you used in the .blend file, open you file then go to File -> External Data -> Pack all into .blend, that way the external images you used are going to be in the file. Send it again afterwards please.